# How to use a proxy with the instagram-private-api for Node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy, instagram-api

**Using a proxy with instagram-private-api.**

Hi all, I spent a decent amount of time trying to figure this out and there is probably a really simple answer but I was seriously confused. When creating a session needed for the **Instagram nodeJS API (private)** you need a proxyUrl. I was wondering how to do / configure this? Do you need to create your own proxy server that you host?

Here is my code so far.

```
var Upload = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('test');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + 
'/cookies/test.json');
var photo = require('instagram-private-api').V1;

var username = 'testusername'
var password = 'testpassword'
var proxyUrl = '???'


Client.Session.create(device, storage, username, password, proxyUrl)
var Upload = require('./node_modules/instagram-private-api/client/v1/Upload.js')
var session = new Client.Session(device, storage, 'test', 'test')

Upload.photo(session, 'aaaa.jpg')
        .then(function(upload) {
            console.log(upload.params.uploadId);

            return Media.configurePhoto(session, upload.params.uploadId, 'henlo world');

        })

        .then(function(medium) {
            console.log(medium.params)
        })
```

I know my code is probably seriously flawed as well, criticism is appreciated! Here's the link to the GitHub of the Node.JS wrapper mentioned. [Here](https://github.com/huttarichard/instagram-private-api).

Comment: For what it is worth, you may want to consider using the official Instagram API and coding for that. This library you are using is no longer maintained by the creator and in my experience with Instagram, things will change and you will be at the mercy of bug fixes.

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e
Hi there Benjamin,

I'm really looking forward to helping you.

As already stated, this library won't be upkept and maintained and could become irrelevant in updates to the official API.

I believe one has to set up a proxy url on their phone.